# Подсчет скидки от суммы

Tags: jquery

> При выборе чекбоксов, нужно посчитать скидку. Скидка 12% от 5 шт.

```
<label for="Bort">Борт у стены</label>
<span id="price4">1100</span>
<input type="checkbox"  id="Bort" /><br>
<label for="Borta">Борта у стены</label>
<span id="price5">2200</span>
<input type="checkbox"   id="Borta" /><br>
<label for="Bok_pereg">Боковая перегородка</label>
<span id="price6">350</span>
<input  type="checkbox" id="Bok_pereg" /> <br>
<label for="count">Итого:</label>
<span id="final_price">5600</span> руб <br>
Скидка 12% от 5 шт <br>
<input type="number" id="count" name="Количество" value="1"  /> шт
```

> jQuery

```
     $('#count').keyup(calculate);
    function calculate() {
    var sum = 0;

       //услуги подсчет добавляются к сумме автоматически
      if ($("#Bort").is(':checked')) sum += 1100; 

      if ($("#Borta").is(':checked')) sum += 2200;

      if ($("#Bok_pereg").is(':checked')) sum += 350;

      //количество товара: 
      var count = $("#count").val(); 
      sum = count * sum; 

//со скидкои 12%
var count = $("#count").val(); 
  if(count >= 5){
   sum = count * (sum - (sum * 12) / 100); 
  } else{
   sum = count * sum; 
  }
  if(count >= 10){
   sum2 = count * (sum - (sum * 23) / 100); 
  } else{
   sum2 = count * sum; 
  }
//итоговая цена cо скидкой
  $('#final_price_skidka').html(sum);
  //итоговая цена cо скидкой
  $('#final_price_skidka2').html(sum2);


      //итоговая цена
      $('#final_price').html(sum);

    }

    $('select,input').change(function() {
      calculate();

    });
```

[полный код](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/131696/)

Comment: а что не так с приведенным кодом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, можно сделать так:

```js
$('#count').keyup(calculate);
function calculate() {
var sum = 0;

   //услуги подсчет добавляются к сумме автоматически
  if ($("#Bort").is(':checked')) sum += 1100; 
  
  if ($("#Borta").is(':checked')) sum += 2200;
  
  if ($("#Bok_pereg").is(':checked')) sum += 350;
  
  //количество товара: 
  var count = $("#count").val(); 
  if(count >= 5){
   sum = count * (sum - (sum * 12) / 100); 
  } else{
   sum = count * sum; 
  }
 

  //итоговая цена
  $('#final_price').html(sum);
  
}

$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="Bort">Борт у стены</label>
<span id="price4">1100</span>
<input type="checkbox"  id="Bort" /><br>
<label for="Borta">Борта у стены</label>
<span id="price5">2200</span>
<input type="checkbox"   id="Borta" /><br>
<label for="Bok_pereg">Боковая перегородка</label>
<span id="price6">350</span>
<input  type="checkbox" id="Bok_pereg" /> <br>
<label for="count">Итого:</label>
<span id="final_price">5600</span> руб <br>
Скидка 12% от 5 шт <br>
<input type="number" id="count" name="Количество" value="1"  /> шт
```

Comment: что поменялось по сравнению с исходным кодом?

Comment: @Grundy разница  с исходным кодом в том, что там не расчитывалась скидка, в моём примере идёт расчёт ))

Comment: Почему не рассчитывалась? там вполне есть код соответствующий расчету `sum - (sum * 12 / 100)` где `sum` - это общая сумма

Comment: @Арсен Спасибо,все работает!!!

Comment: @Арсен подскажите,пожалуйста, добавляю вторую скидку и не верно считает:  if(count >= 10){
   sum2 = count * (sum - (sum * 23) / 100); 
  } else{
   sum2 = count * sum; 
  }

Comment: @Лиана а как вставляете вторую скидку? покажите код в вашем вопросе (обновите ваш вопрос)

Comment: @Арсен поправила

Comment: @Арсен с else if  вообще не работает...

Comment: @Лиана я проверил, всё норм считает, да там else дублиреутся у вас.

Comment: @Арсен а Вы можете мне показать код, у меня не работает...